# Count the TEXT and Numeric Values form specific Range with Line Break

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using below formula which calulcates the Leaves status from the specific range of dates these dates are comes with TEXT or Numeric values and my formula is calculating the results wrong.

I have tried with different formulas like LEN(SUBSTITUTE to count the Line Breaks but nothing is working. I have attached a Sheet for your reference. I hope someone can help me Thanks.

[sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sNTOUIIPPfC6qetoaSpKOEF8UrZZBYaaC7TXNtDGKGM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IF(G3<>"",LEN(TRIM(G3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(G3),",",""))+1,"0")+IF(H3<>"",LEN(TRIM(H3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(H3),",",""))+1,"")/2+IF(I3<>"",LEN(TRIM(I3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(I3),",",""))+1,"")/4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this formula, combining BYROW and BYCOL:

```
=BYROW(G3:I,LAMBDA(c,SUM(BYCOL(c,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(r,CHAR(10),1)))*INDEX(1:1,1,COLUMN(r)))))))

=BYROW(J3:L,LAMBDA(c,SUM(BYCOL(c,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(r,CHAR(10),1)))*INDEX(1:1,1,COLUMN(r)))))))
```

PS: had to change 1/2 and 1/4 since they were considered as dates instead of fractions

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to replace the `0` with blank @Martín

Comment: Try adding a check with ARRAYFORMULA. Here I wrapped it in LAMBDA to make it shorter. But basically you add this pattern. It checks if it's 0, it returns "", and if it isn't it returns the value of BYROW:  `=LAMBDA(f,INDEX(IF(f=0, "", f)))
(BYROW(J3:L.....)`  I added it to your sheet